# Report Plus: Issue with filtering campaigns

Tags: civireport, reports

We've found an issue with Report Plus. The extension doesn't show the choosed campaign (via filters) in the results. So if we choose to filter for Campaign A, it shows another different campaign. This happens for all campaigns.
We use the latest version of Report Plus.

Does someone else have the same issue or has any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a campaign related Issue reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/reportplus/-/issues - does it sound like the same issue?

Comment: Yes, it's from me :) 
I've posted it here and there.

Comment: cool. helps is you cross reference -- unless i just beat you to it